# Flags needed to create static binaries in golang

Tags: go, build, compilation

I was building a Docker image using `scratch` as base.

The following build command:

```
RUN go build -o /go/bin/myapp
```

created a binary that kept failing when executed:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

By trial and error I found out that I needed to build as follows:

```
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o /go/bin/myapp -a -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' .
```

Why are both `CGO_ENABLED=0` **and** `-ldflags '-extldflags "-static"'` necessary?

Don't both options create static binaries? (i.e. binaries that will need absolutely nothing in terms of libraries from the environments they will run on?)

Comment: Some systems do not really allow totally static binaries. Other work better if you use the system provided stuff (e.g. name resolution). Disabling cgo makes sure no C code is used while -static instructs the linker to statically link everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just before we start, a heads up by Russ Cox's: [Comment](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26492#issuecomment-407193609)

Read this as well: [Comment](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26492#issuecomment-525527016)

Yes, I agree with Volker's comment that some systems don't really allow static binaries.

Read on: [Compile packages and dependencies](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies)

```
-a
    force rebuilding of packages that are already up-to-date.

-ldflags '[pattern=]arg list'
    arguments to pass on each go tool link invocation.
```

Read: [go tool link](https://golang.org/cmd/link/)

```
-extldflags flags
    Set space-separated flags to pass to the external linker.
```

Hence, it tries to rebuild all the packages (dependencies as well) with CGO disabled and also `-static` means do not link against shared libraries.

Some of the points related to static linking are explained well: [Linking golang statically](https://blog.hashbangbash.com/2014/04/linking-golang-statically/)